# Computer going to sleep and silverlight app

Tags: silverlight-2.0

When computer goes to sleep and if the Silverlight application is open(in IE) then what happens? When computer wakes up will the connection betweeen the Server and the silverlight app in IE still holds good? Currently when I tested on my silverlight application which uses WCF service then it shows different results each time, sometimes it works and sometimes not. Could any please shed some light on this?

Many thanks
Sai

Answer (score 0):

The silverlight application is running locally and does not persist any connection with the server.  Even the calls to the webservices are Async so the connection is not persisted.

What kind of connection are you talking about?